# How to make UTF-8 in request-promise?

Tags: node.js, utf-8

I made a request with [Request-Promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) with umlauts after the request:

```
var file = rp({uri: serviceURL, encoding: 'utf8'}).forEach(function (polizeistelle) {
    console.log(polizeistelle)
}
```

In the console log it says 'pr�si' instead of 'präsi'

Thanks for help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because the `serviceURL` is not delivering utf8. Here `utf-8` is not converting to utf8, but merely tells to interpret the response as utf8.

You should use

```
rp({uri: serviceURL, encoding: 'latin1'})
```

to read the response correctly, and convert it to utf8 afterwards, if you need to.

Comment: you can also set `encoding: 'latin1'` on default options when importing `request-promise`.

`const rp = require('request-promise').defaults({ encoding: 'latin1' })`